# TikZ: Arrow hidden by circle around node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

**Context**
I would like to draw lines between nodes to indicate a dependence relationship. The nodes are drawn as circles. Unfortunately the arrow is hidden by the circle.

**Question**
How can I shorten the line such that there is a gap between the line and both circles?

**Code**

```
\draw [color=black, fill=black] (1.00, 0.00) circle (.1);
\draw [color=black, fill=black] (2.00, 0.00) circle (.1);
\draw (1.00, 1.00);
\draw (2.00, 1.00);
\draw [color=white] (2.25, 1.25) circle (.1);
\path [draw, ->] (1.00, 0.00) -- (2.00, 0.00);
\path [draw, ->] (1.00, 1.00) -- (2.00, 1.00);
```

**Output**:

[image: Two lines, headed with an arrow on the right side.]

Comment: Use actual nodes for the circles. Give these nodes names, and connect them as usual (use their names as coordinates).

Comment: Like Qrrbrbirlbel, use actual nodes. Also, you don't need to specify `(1.00, 2.00)` in the coordinates, `(1,2)` is enough. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Options `shorten >` and `shorten <` can be used to shorten a line or arrow.
The following example shortens the arrow at both ends by the radius of the circles and some extra space, e.g. the line width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [color=black, fill=black, radius=.1]
  (1, 0) circle[]
  (2, 0) circle[]
;
\draw [
  ->,
  shorten <=.1cm + \pgflinewidth,
  shorten >=.1cm + \pgflinewidth,
] (1, 0) -- (2, 0);
\draw [->] (1, 1) -- (2, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

While it was being suggested to you in the comments, I was slightly modifying your code to show you that you should have used nodes. The arrow properties can also be set globally in the `\tikzpicture` options without having to type it in each arrow, by using the Tikz library `arrows.meta`.

I also think that if you need to *draw* arrows, you're better off saying `\draw ...` than `\path[draw] ...`, which is very useful for drawing invisible paths for calculating coordinates.

Lastly, I'm not sure what the commands in the middle were supposed to do:

```
\draw (1.00, 1.00);
\draw (2.00, 1.00);
\draw [color=white] (2.25, 1.25) circle (.1);
```

Except for the circle (not at either side of the arrows), the other commands didn't do anything (if I missed their purpose, let me know).

[image: figure 1]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->] % add ,>=latex or ,>=stealth to change arrow tip

\node [circle, draw, fill=black] (a1) at (1,0) {};
\node [circle, draw, fill=black] (a2) at (2,0) {};

\node [circle, draw, fill=white] (b1) at (1,1) {};
\node [circle, draw, fill=white] (b2) at (2,1) {};

\draw (a1) -- (a2);
\draw (b1) -- (b2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. :) Indeed it's somehow meaningful that connections between nodes are adjusted to the node size. Unfortunately I did not came up with that on my own ;) Actually I really need some more space between line and circle such that I will stick with Heiko's answer.

Comment: @Christoph Just for your info: you can use shorten also with nodes. See [my answer to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241453/4778). In case you want to use both things, you can do it. :)